# Ubuntu apt upgrade = 1 monitor stuck in 1024x768 (same graphics card)

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, amd-graphics, dvi

I have a graphics card with 4 DVI outputs. Before apt upgrading, I had them all in 1920x1080... now I am stuck in 1024x768 on one.

Here's the output of `xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 4864 x 1536, maximum 16384 x 16384 DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) DisplayPort-1 connected primary 1024x768+3840+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm 1024x768 60.00* 800x600 60.32 56.25
848x480 60.00
640x480 59.94
DisplayPort-2 connected 1024x768+3840+768 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm 1024x768 60.00* 800x600 60.32 56.25
848x480 60.00
640x480 59.94
HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm 1920x1080 60.00*+ 1280x1024 75.02 60.02
1152x864 75.00
1024x768 75.08 60.00
800x600 75.00 60.32
640x480 75.00 60.00
720x400 70.08
HDMI-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm 1920x1080 60.00*+ 1280x1024 75.02 60.02
1152x864 75.00
1024x768 75.08 60.00
800x600 75.00 60.32
640x480 75.00 60.00
720x400 70.08
```

Comment: It looks like your DisplayPort monitor's EDID is not getting through. What graphics card? Standard driver or Additional (nvidia) driver? Same behaviour from both DisplayPorts?

Comment: it's a Dell XPS 8500. Here's my lspci:

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Turks PRO [Radeon HD 6570/7570/8550]

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution: run xrandr to list your monitors (ie, DisplayPort-1, DisplayPort-2, HDMI-0, HDMI-1 is returned for me)

then add your desired resolution via: xrandr --addmode DisplayPort-1 1900x1280

then simply go to System Settings -> Displays and select your resolution from the drop down :)

Comment: Glad you managed to find a solution. Can you confirm if this survives a system restart?